# VPN site to site via VPS

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, vpn, strongswan

I would like to do connection:
MY_PC (Private IP) <==> VPS (Public IP) <==> Raspberry Pi (GSM - Private IP).
What soultion are You prefare for this connection? I would like to have a MY_PC and a Raspberry Pi in the same network.

Comment: Hello, your question will probably not get an answer, the solution could either be a SSH Tunnel a IPSec VPN an OpenVPN use of hamachi well lost of different possibility and there's few chances we will be able to explain to you all the steps to do so as everything will be specific to your setup. I would personnaly prefer IPSec VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of options for this, depending on your exact needs.  Just a few examples:

- Set up a persistent SSH tunnel from the Pi to the VPS with a port-forward setup something like this:

  ```
  ssh -L 22:localhost:2200 user@vps -n
  ```

  And then use the VPS as a SSH jump host from your computer like so:

  ```
  ssh -J user@vps user@localhost
  ```

  This will give you easy shell access to the Pi, as well as SFTP and SCP support and the ability to forward arbitrary ports from your local system to the Pi, but won't simulate a network.
- Set the VPS up as a conventional VPN server, and connect to it persistently from both your computer and the Pi.  OpenVPN works reasonably well for this, as does IPSec (a bit more complicated to set up, but more efficient than OpenVPN).  This is probably the easiest to set up method to get what you're talking about, but may cause performance issues on the Pi depending on what VPN software you use.
- My preferred option, use [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/), and set up both the Pi and your local computer to connect to the VPN.  Tinc has a couple of distinct advantages, notably including the fact that it has miniscule resource usage compared to a lot of other VPN options, is very easy to set up, and supports mesh topologies (which means that it can also do real-time failover routing if you have multiple paths between the source and destination).